# Overriding a WPF Style

Tags: wpf, xaml

New to WPF and XAML styling. I have created a WPF Resource Library which holds my custom styles. Within this library I have a style xml for my default border element.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <!--  Border  -->
    <Style x:Key="BorderBase" TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Ivory" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray" />
    </Style>
    
    <Style
        x:Key="FrameBorder"
        BasedOn="{StaticResource BorderBase}"
        TargetType="Border">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="4" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="10" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="6" />
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

I then include these styles in my app.xml like so

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/WPFResourceLibrary;component/ResourceDictionaryBorder.xaml" />
    ...
</ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

This works fine, however I want to be able to override the BorderBase definition on an application by application basis.  I have tried redefining BorderBase in my app.xml (both before and after the merging of the dictionaries but this doesn't work.

If I remove BorderBase from my library i get a runtime error indicating BorderBase is not defined.  Is what I am trying to achieve posible, and what have I missed?

Comment: What you actually tried when _I have tried redefining BorderBase in my app.xml_ ? A Style defined in the lower in xaml should prevail.

Comment: Are you trying to override a value of `BorderBase` derived to `FrameBorder` so that it is reflected in `FrameBorder` in the separate assembly?

Comment: That is correct - I want to be able to define BorderBase in my app.xaml so that it takes precedence over the definition in the sub assembly.
The other alternative is to not define it in the library and then define it in my app.xaml - in which case how does this work?

Comment: `FrameBorder` in ResourceDictionaryBorder.xaml refers `BorderBase` in that xaml. No other `BorderBase` can be referred by that `FrameBorder`. Thus, I don't think other `BorderBase` defined elsewhere can affect that `FrameBorder`.

Comment: Resources are a key value pair. Look up by key and get whatever the value is. When you merge a resource dictionary into application resources ( or any resources ) a later resource with the same key ( eg BorderBase ) replaces one that was there. So whichever resource dictionary you merge last in app.xaml will "win"

Comment: "So whichever resource dictionary you merge last in app.xaml "  Am I reading this right that the way to override the default settings to to put the desired items into a merged dictionary rather than just adding tme as an inline style in app.xaml?